# How to set default value in chain selected with php mysql jquery

Tags: jquery

Most of work as chain selected with php mysql jquery.
But could not set default value. 
some code works but stop chain...

Assume id = 17

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "region_action2.php", 
                    data: {"parent_id": "1", "type": "1"},                  
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {                        
                        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                            **// $("#provinces select").val(17); //does not work**
                            **$('#provinces option[value=17]').attr('selected','selected'); //works but #citys valus did not show.**
                            $("#provinces").append("<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.english + "</option>");

                        });
                    }
                });

                $("#provinces").change(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "get",
                        url: "region_action2.php", 
                        data: {"parent_id": $(this).val(), "type": "2"},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {
                            //$("#citys").html("<option value=''>Select Postcode</option>");
                            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                                //$('#citys option[value=12543]').attr('selected','selected');
                                $("#citys").append("<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.english + "</option>");
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }); ...

 </script>
<div>
            State：
            <select name="trop_1_id" id="provinces">
                <option value="" >Select State2</option>
            </select>
            Postcode：
            <select name="trop_2_id" id="citys">
                <option value="">Select Postcode</option>
            </select>
            Suburb：
            ...
        </div>
```

Most of work as chain selected with php mysql jquery.
But could not set default value. 
some code works but stop chain...
Thanks for any help

Comment: Typing the question twice doesn't make it make any more sense. I don't see any PHP or MySQL in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This could be written many ways.

The code below uses :

- default values hard-coded in the HTML.
- a `getOptions()` function, for calling `$.ajax()` (and returning a [jqXHR promise](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)).
- a `.setOptions()` [jQuery plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/), for replacing a select element's options with new ones constructed from the `data` object delivered by `.setOptions()`.

**HTML**

```
<select id="provinces" data-default="17"></select>
<select id="cities" data-default="22"></select>
<select id="suburbs" data-default="95"></select>
```

Each select tag includes a custom `data` attribute to define its default value. If it's impossible/inconvenient to achieve this, then the same effect can be achieved in javascript.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getOptions(id, type) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'region_action2.php',
            data: { 'parent_id': id, 'type': type },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }

    // jQuery plugin for constructing a select element's options from a data object delivered by getOptions().
    // Also, default value is set, and set downstream select elements are cleared/populated.
    $.fn.setOptions = function (data) {
        var self = this.empty() // clear #suburbs and keep reference to `this` for use in the inner function
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            var $option = $('<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.english + '</option>').appendTo(self);
        });
        return self.val(self.data('default')) // set default value
            .nextAll('select').empty() // clear all downstream selects
            .end().trigger('change'); // trigger 'change' on this select
    };

    // *** attach change handlers to `#provinces`, `#cities` etc ***
    $("#provinces").change(function() {
        if(this.selectedIndex > -1) {
            getOptions(this[this.selectedIndex].value, '2').then(function(data) {
                $("#cities").setOptions(data) // create new #cities options and trigger downstream changes.
            });
        }
    });
    $("#cities").change(function() { // note: plural of "city" is "cities"
        if(this.selectedIndex > -1) {
            getOptions(this[this.selectedIndex].value, '3').then(function(data) {
                $("#suburbs").setOptions(data) // create new #suburbs options and trigger downstream changes.
            });
        }
    });

    // *** initialize `#provinces` ***
    getOptions('1', '1').then(function(data) {
        $("#provinces").setOptions(data) // create new #provinces options and trigger downstream changes.
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7ohynr04/1/)**

Comment: Hi Roamer-1888, Thanks for your reply.
I tried the code above, does not work.
how about getOptions('1', '1') ?

--- mysql Fields: 
id, parent_id, english.

I am very appreciated with your help!

Comment: Take another look. I've made some major changes .... and tested everything this time.